# I was wondering how I could convert my console output into a processing window in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

With the following code how could I import my other console program class into this other class which will create the java window.

```
import processing.core.PApplet;


public class Runner extends PApplet {
    
    public void settings() {
        this.size(600, 600);
    }
    
    
    
    public void setup() {
        
        
    }
    
    int col;
    int row;
    
    public void draw() {
        
        background(col, row);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about importing from another class within the same Java "program", you can [create an instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) of another class and call your method.

For example

```
 public class Runner extends PApplet {
   //rest of your code
   AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
   //assume your method returning String. 

   public void draw() {
        background(col, row);
        text(a.methodFromAnotherClass(), 50, 100);
    }
   //rest of your code
```

If you are asking about importing from another "console program", you have to [build and create JAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) file of your another Java program and you can import it into your current program, by moving it to the lib folder.